# Is it possible to insert Repeating Control in SharePoint 2010 List Infopath Form?

Tags: infopath

I see from here (excerpt from Microsoft site) that it probably ISN'T supported, but I thought I'd double check!!

**Inserting Repeating Data Controls**

Insert a repeating recursive section

Note    You can insert a Repeating Recursive Section control only in a form that was created using the Blank Form (InfoPath Filler) form template, or that has Compatibility set to InfoPath Filler Form in the Form Options dialog box.

---

asking because this is what I see in my Compatibility dialog:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Nope, it's a limitation in SharePoint List InfoPath forms.

Comment: is this fixed in 2013??

Comment: There are no improvements on InfoPath in 2013, just the addition of one small feature "Online Pictures", and that's it. But nothing dealing with list forms.

Comment: what about handling Managed Metadata?? I thought 2013 allows for that too (2010 does NOT)

Comment: It's the same as 2010, no functionality added.

Answer (score 0):

We can add repeating section in SharePoint List form with Main data source if selected the option "Manage multiple items with this form" when tried to create a SharePoint List form as in attached [image]

Answer (score 0):

No, repeating control can be added to any type of InfoPath form templates like form library, blank template, etc, except the list type form - this is a limitation in the InfoPath list form.